# Windows Issue with Scrapy and Anaconda

Tags: python, scrapy, anaconda, conda

I successfully download `Scrapy 2.1.0` and I can see it in my Anaconda Navigator's installed environment. I open Anaconda Prompt, go to the directory I want, and try to run scrapy startproject tutorial; however, I see this error:

```
"Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"d:\bld\scrapy_1587736721630\_h_env\python.exe" 
"C:\Users\david\anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy.exe"` 
startproject tutorial': The system cannot find the file specified."
```

What should I do to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: It is a [known issue](https://github.com/conda-forge/scrapy-feedstock/issues/37).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Gallaecio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939364/gallaecio) pointed out in the comment, this is an ongoing and known issue.

Until this is fixed you can add `python -m` at the beginning to make it work. So for example you can use
`python -m scrapy startproject tutorial` to set up a project.